# Golang: Multiple SQL query generate extra empty {{range.}}

Tags: sql, postgresql, templates, go

> In the application, I will use totally different query for the second
>   query. The second query will be quite long `SELECT SIMILARITY` query.
>   In this question, I give simple query to make it easier to understand

I need to print data from PostgreSQL in template. Everything works fine but output HTML has extra `range`.

Below is the HTML output. You can see the extra `range` that have no value:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Content</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Nation</td>
        <td>Nation has various meanings, and the meaning has changed over time</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</table>

<h1>ID number:</h1>

<h3></h3>

<h3>5</h3>
```

Below is `server.go`

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "html/template"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Gallery struct {
    Title, Content, Idnumber string
}

type (
    Template struct {
        templates *template.Template
    }
)

func (t *Template) Render(w io.Writer, name string, data interface{}) *echo.HTTPError {
    if err := t.templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, data); err != nil {
        return &echo.HTTPError{Error: err}
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=postgres password=apassword dbname=lesson4 sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    t := &Template{
        templates: template.Must(template.ParseFiles("public/views/testhere.html")),
    }
    e.Renderer(t)

    e.Get("/post/:uritext", func(c *echo.Context) *echo.HTTPError {

        rows, err := db.Query("SELECT title, content FROM gallery WHERE uri=$1", c.Param("uritext"))
        anotherquery, err := db.Query("SELECT id AS idnumber FROM gallery WHERE uri=$1", c.Param("uritext"))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        gallery := []Gallery{}

        for rows.Next() {
            g := Gallery{}
            err := rows.Scan(&g.Title, &g.Content)

            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            gallery = append(gallery, g)
        }

        for anotherquery.Next() {
            g := Gallery{}
            err := anotherquery.Scan(&g.Idnumber)

            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            gallery = append(gallery, g)
        }

        return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "onlytestingtpl", gallery)
    })

    e.Run(":4444")
}
```

Below is template `public/views/testhere.html`

```
{{define "onlytestingtpl"}}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Content</th>
    </tr>
    {{range.}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{.Title}}</td>
        <td>{{.Content}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{end}}
</table>

<h1>ID number:</h1>
{{range.}}
<h3>{{.Idnumber}}</h3>
{{end}}

{{end}}
```

I have feeling about the `range` in template but I have no idea since no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks right to me. You are running two separate queries:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT title, content FROM gallery WHERE uri=$1", c.Param("uritext"))
anotherquery, err := db.Query("SELECT id AS idnumber FROM gallery WHERE uri=$1", c.Param("uritext"))
```

And then creating a slice from both:

```
gallery = append(gallery, g)
gallery = append(gallery, g)
```

So you have two rows:

```
{ "Nation", "Nation...", 0 }
{ "", "", 5 }
```

Is that what you wanted? If you want them merged you can just change your query to:

```
SELECT title, content, id as idnumber FROM gallery WHERE uri=$1
```

If you wanted two separate lists then maybe you should have two separate types:

```
type Gallery struct {
    Title, Content string
}
type IDNumber string
```

Build two separate lists and use a combined object for your render:

```
type Model struct {
    Galleries []Gallery
    IDNumbers []IDNumber
}
return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "onlytestingtpl", Model{
    Galleries: galleries,
    IDNumbers: idnumbers,
})
```

And your template ends up with:

```
{{range .Galleries}}
<tr>
    <td>{{.Title}}</td>
    <td>{{.Content}}</td>
</tr>
{{end}}
```

Comment: In the application, I will use totally different query for the second query. The second query will be quite long `SELECT SIMILARITY` query. In above question, I gave simple query to make it easier to understand

Comment: I'm now trying to understand, and still unable to make it work

Answer (score 1):

You are not scanning title and content in your `anotherquery`:

```
err := anotherquery.Scan(&g.Idnumber)
```

So the `g`'s title and content are set to empty string.

Comment: Did you mean like this?: `err := anotherquery.Scan(&g.Title, &g.Content, &g.Idnumber)`. Sorry, I hard to understand

Comment: @apasajja Yes. Otherwise, you're only scanning the `Idnumber`.

Comment: Error `sql: expected 1 destination arguments in Scan, not 3` showing up when running the code you're suggested. I thing it because of the second query select one column. I cannot merge the queries because this is placeholder query. The real query is quite long.

Comment: I realized what Caleb said is right. Go confuse about the `range`, so that it inherit each other. I need to make both range different.